# Emacs symbol's value as variable is void

Tags: emacs

I have following code in my emacs init file -

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/solarized")
(load-theme 'solarized-light t)
```

I get following error -

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: custom-theme-load-path
```

Backtrace of the error is -

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable custom-theme-load-path)
  add-to-list(custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/solarized")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/kshitiz/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 69
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/kshitiz/.emacs" "/home/kshitiz/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[nil "\205\264
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's your Emacs version?

Comment: The variable `custom-theme-load-path` doesn't exist when you call `add-to-list`. Maybe you need to load a package that defines the variable first.

Comment: @abo-abo `GNU Emacs 23.4.1`

Comment: @Barmar Perhaps. But i'm following the guide [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/zenburn-emacs) and it doesn't mention such a thing.

Comment: From the documentation there: _This theme uses the new built-in theming support available starting with **Emacs 24**._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The theming support that this depends on is only available in Emacs 24.x, but you're running Emacs 23.x.